Использование aiohttp на базе ASGI сервера
Есть какое-то приложение, которое выполняется при помощи aiohttp.
from aiohttp import web

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                web.get('/{name}', handle)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)

Проблема заключается в том, что необходимо каким-нибудь образом запустить aiohttp сервер на базе ASGI сервера hypercorn (аналог uvicorn). Проблема заключается в том, что библиотека aiohttp не поддерживает стандарт ASGI (issue 1, issue 2), за счёт чего запуск такого приложения на этом стандарте невозможен.
Какие могут существовать решения данной проблемы?
Мне известна библиотека aiohttp-asgi, которая позволяет запустить FastAPI приложение вместе с приложением на aiohttp. Но данный вариант меня не устраивает, т.к. в проект будет добавлено огромное количество зависимостей (FastAPI, Starlette, httpx, jinja2, python-multipart и т. д.).
Важным ограничением является то, что запускаться приложение должно на чистом hypercorn
без использования каких-то форков, вмешательств в код сервера, специальных параметров запуска asgi-приложения и т. д.
Считаю важным также отметить, что сервера со стандартом ASGI в Python использует словари и списки в качестве интерфейсных структур данных, когда как aiohttp успешно применяет свою библиотеку multidict.

При том, что эта библиотека позволяет запустить aiohttp-сервер вместе с asgi-приложением, что не будет являться решением.

А мне нужно наоборот, запустить aiohttp-приложение на базе asgi-сервера.

А, ну так и нужно было написать в тексте вопроса, а не замусоривать его непонятным «в проект будет добавлено огромное количество зависимостей»
